# how to generate end date from start date with specific list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, datetime

```
shift_lst = ["D","D","D","D","N","N","W","N","N","D","D","D","D","W","N","N","N"]

current_date = date(2021, 4, 1)

for shift in (shift_lst):
    shift_dict=dict()
    if shift == 'D':
       shift_type = 'S1'
       while shift_type == 'S1':
       # start_date = current_date
       # enddate = start_date + timedelta(days=count)
       count = count + 1

    elif shift == 'N':
       shift='S2'
       start_date = current_date
       # enddate = start_date + timedelta(days=count)
       count = count + 1
```

Output :

> {shift : S1,'start_date':2021,4,1,'end_date':2021,4,4},

> {shift : S2,'start_date':2021,4,5,'end_date':2021,4,9},

> {shift : S1,'start_date':2021,4,11,'end_date':2021,4,13}

I have list of Shift
In that list i have D (Day shift) then date should start from 1st april to enddate until N not come then when N Start so start date also start from enddate of "D" and create dictionary of shift

Comment: Well, what does `W` stand for? Week shift? Can you explain your problem in the clearer way?

Comment: Can you explain it cleaner, It's so confusing.

Comment: @HabibMhamadi Im really sorry simply what i want if shift == D then i want  start date and end date of D, for example in first how many times D appear it 4 times so start date =2021-04-01 and end date = 2021-04-04 thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be what you are looking for. There is no need for `while` loop inside. You just increment your `current_date` when it is `D` or `W`.

```
current_date = date(2021, 4, 1)

print("start date: ", current_date)

for shift in (shift_lst):
    if shift == "D":
        current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    elif shift == "W":
        current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(weeks=1)
    elif shift == "N":
        current_date = current_date
    print(current_date)

end_date = current_date

print("end date: ", end_date)
```

output:

```
start date:  2021-04-01
2021-04-02
2021-04-03
2021-04-04
2021-04-05
2021-04-05
2021-04-05
2021-04-12
2021-04-12
2021-04-12
2021-04-13
2021-04-14
2021-04-15
2021-04-16
2021-04-23
2021-04-23
2021-04-23
2021-04-23
end date:  2021-04-23
```

Comment: Im really sorry simply what i want if shift == D then i want start date and end date of D, for example in first how many times D appear it 4 times so start date =2021-04-01 and end date = 2021-04-04 thats it same to N also from when N start and end i want just start date end date

Comment: Smply in your output how many time "D" appear in first 4 times right until "N" not come, so  just in new dictionary (shift_dict) start_date = 2021-04-01 end_date = 2021-04-04 and shifttype=S1 like i answered the question after please check

Answer (score 0):

simply what i want if shift == D then i want start date and end date of D, for example in first how many times D appear it 4 times so start date =2021-04-01 and end date = 2021-04-04 that's it same to N also from when N start and end i want just start date end date and create new dictionary for shift_type

```
current_date = date(2021, 4, 1)

print("start date: ", current_date)

for shift in (shift_lst):
    shift_dict=dict()
    if shift == "D":
        shift_type='S1'
        current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    elif shift == "W":
        current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(weeks=1)
    elif shift == "N":
        shift_type='S2'
        current_date = current_date
    print(current_date)

end_date = current_date
shift_dict['shift_type']=shift
shift_dict['start_date']=current_date
shift_dict['end_date']=enddate
```

Output :

> {shift_type:S1,"start_date":"2021,4,1","end_date":"2021,4,4"}
> {shift_type:S2,"start_date":"2021,4,5","end_date":"2021,4,9"}